# .htaccess subdominio coringa (wildcard) e específico

Tags: htaccess

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de arquivos (exemplo):

```
/usuarios
/admin
.htaccess
```

consegui com sucesso, configurar o .htaccess para que, ao acessar os url abaixo, todos sejam direcionados para a pasta usuários, e exibe o url como foi digitado, e não exibindo a pasta dominio.com.br/usuarios

```
fulano.dominio.com.br
ciclano.dominio.com.br
etc.dominio.com.br
```

usei o seguinte código

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.dominio\.com\.br
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/usuarios
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /usuarios/$1 [L,NC]
```

Nesse caso, qualquer subdominio da url, será direcionada a pasta usuarios, e exibe a url sem a pasta, mantendo o link correto com subdominio (ex: fulano.dominio.com.br).

**Agora minha dúvida...**

Preciso criar uma exceção, ao acessar

```
leandro.dominio.com.br
admin.dominio.com.br
```

quero que a pasta de destino seja a "admin", ou seja, preciso criar exceções e manter a função de ser redirecionado para a pasta sem trocar a url

**Minha tentativa** (não conheço muito de htaccess)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^leandro\.dominio\.com\.br
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.dominio\.com\.br
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/usuarios
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /usuarios/$1 [L,NC]
```

Nesse caso ao acessar fulano.dominio.com.br funciona, o conteúdo da pasta "usuarios" é exibida, mas ao tentar acessar leandro, é exibido erro

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@pokerweb.com.br to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Qual a sintaxe correta para o .htaccess para esse meu caso?

Já agradeço qualquer tentativa de ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

achei a solução, para quem tiver a mesma dúvida que eu, segue abaixo...

o que estava acontecendo era um conflito entre as duas regras (script que incluí na pergunta como "Tentativa"), o que fiz foi remover as exceções da regra do wildcard, ficando assim

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^leandro\.dominio\.com\.br
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.dominio\.com\.br
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !leandro\.dominio\.com\.br
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/usuarios
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /usuarios/$1 [L,NC]
```

Na primeira Regra, se acessar leandro.dominio.com.br ele exibe os arquivos do diretorio "admin"

Na segunda Regra, qualquer dominio que eu digitar, exceto "leandro", será direcionado para a pasta usuarios